# Google App Engine, Billing "Minimum Spend $2.10 Per Week"?

Tags: google-app-engine

When I try to enable billing in app engine for using blob store, I found a notice for Minimum Spend $2.10 Per Week.

> The Minimum spend subtotal is in support of our new pricing model. The new model requires that you spend at least $2.10/week. This subtotal indicates the value beyond your other spend that we need to add to your contract. To make the transition to the new model smoother we are beginning to account for this minimum when we authorize new budget changes. Please note that you will not be charged for the minimum spend until our new model takes effect.

I search online and found no one ask about it. I use app engine just for a school assignment, so the usage won't be excess free quota. So, Must I pay $2.10 per week even I do not  excess free quota? It sounds unreasonable.

Comment: If you're not going to exceed the free quota, why enable billing?

Comment: Hi Cameron, because app engine require application enable billing to use blob store, right?

Comment: Ah. I'm not as up-to-date with App Engine as I used to be :-)

Comment: @Cliff That is not correct - you can use the blob store without enabling billing.

Comment: this needs a new accepted answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of April 2013, "We’re happy to [announce](http://googleappengine.blogspot.be/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html) that billing-enabled applications will no longer be required to spend a minimum of $2.10 per week. This means that you can enable billing for a free tier application and continue running within the free tier without concern that a spike in traffic will terminate serving (note that you can always specify a daily dollar budget). The minimum spend was originally intended to prevent abuse and ensure that we can offer a stable, reliable system with a free tier.  We have determined that we can continue to support the free tier, without relying on the minimum spend.  So, goodbye $2.10!"

Comment: according to http://www.google.com/enterprise/cloud/appengine/pricing.html it seems that free apps under the new pricing model will have 5GB of blobstore. But I'm a little bit confused with the terminology so to make sure: the use of the blobstore within the quotas will always be free before and after the new pricing model. Am I right?

Comment: I noticed this when I started getting billed 2.10$ per week - it's not a lot but still... if I am in the free quota why should I be billed. o_O

Comment: @JohnIdol Billed apps are charged a minimum of $2.10/week - see here for details: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Enabling_Paid_Apps

Comment: Thanks Nick. I have to say this is fair, but I only noticed once I started getting billed recently (must've skipped the new agreement etc.) :)

Comment: "We’re happy to announce that billing-enabled applications will no longer be required to spend a minimum of $2.10 per week." - http://googleappengine.blogspot.be/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html

Comment: I am really scared to use appengine because I have no idea what I will get charged when things get busy - people have warned me that its very expensive - who knows?

Comment: @peterretief You can set your maximum spend in the configuration.

Comment: @NickJohnson if a service "stopped" it would be almost as bad as a runaway cost - I really do want to resell and use Google services but I find it difficult to cost (apps for business is also a weird costing model - why must unused email addresses be charged for ie info@domain etc ) It would be nice to have a simple rule of thumb to work with for costing

Comment: @peterretief Well, it's up to you to make the choice between cost and availability in a situation where you get a massive spike in traffic. It's no different in any other system - you either pay for the traffic, or take your site down.

Comment: @NickJohnson There have been issues like deleting of test data running up costs? I am a very small fish in a big pond so got to be careful

Answer (score 8):

Google has removed the $2.10/week for billing-enabled application from now onwards. You can enable billing for a free tier application and continue running within the free tier without concern that a spike in traffic will terminate serving.

http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html

Comment: I'd love to see this get accepted, as it is current/correct by the person getting the rep.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled billing because I needed to add Google Cloud SQL. The notice said that minimal Cloud SQL was free for now. We're still in early development and aren't using any resources, so we're not over the quota for anything. I don't think I was ever advised by any page that I'd be billed even if under the free thresholds. In fact, I think one of the pages explicitly said I would not be.

It really isn't a lot of money. Probably not even if you add all the users who have been deceptively billed together, so it probably won't attract any lawyers. But unless I missed some notice (and even if I did if that notice was intentionally hidden) this is legally wrong, as well as ethically so.

Comment: Billing for Google CLoud SQL and billing for App Engine is not the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that their "new" system hasn't gone into effect yet so I would go ahead and use it. Besides, $2/week compared to the $150/book that I just spend isn't that bad. =/

As for enabling billing it appears that unless you need the new (per 1.5.3 version) unlimited blobstore then you should be fine with the free limits.